# Char to string function

Tags: haskell

I have a very simple question: Given a function accepting a char and returning a string

```
test :: Char -> [String]
```

how can one convert the char into a string? I'm confused over the two types.

Comment: Your question asks about converting a char into a string, but your code block actually involves the types `Char` and `[String]` (instead of `String`). Note that `[String]` means a *list* of `String`s, i.e. (as `String` is defined as `[Char]`) a list of lists of `Char`s.

Comment: Based on OP's comment on the accepted answer I believe they meant `[String]`. Is this edit-worthy? May have been an XY problem where they asked about converting Char to String at which point they would put it into a list most likely with brackets (ironic that that's how you convert Char to String in the first place).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Haskell `String` is an alias for `[Char]`:

```
type String = [Char]
```

If you just want a function that converts a single char to a string you could e.g. do

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]
```

If you prefer pointfree style you could also write

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString = (:[])
```

Comment: I see before i was expecting a output like [c], but have changed to this: [[c]] and it works :) Thanks so simple

Answer (score 5):

A String is just a [Char]

But that's just a nice way of saying

```
'H':'E':'L':'L':'O':[]
```

So to make it a [String] we could do:

```
['H':'E':'L':'L':'O':[]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be using

```
return . return
```

Since `return` for lists is defined as `:[]`

Comment: Prelude> return 'a'    =>   'a'

              Doesn't work (return .return will give an error).

Comment: @paradoja `return` has type `Monad m => a -> m a`. By default, ghci assumes `IO` for the monad instance by default. Since ghci also unwraps (executes) values in the IO monad for you, you see `return` as a no-op. Try `(return :: a -> [a]) 'a'` to fix the monad to lists.

Answer (score -3):

Note that you can convert any type implementing the `Show` type class to a string using `show`:

```
(Show a) => a -> String
```

Because `Char` implements this, the function is already written for you!

Comment: Prelude> show 'a'    =>    
"'a'"   (Doesn't work as probably intended).